# How to take partial screen shot in Full Screen mode?

Tags: microsoft-visio, fullscreen

I use VISIO and hitting PF5 brings the full screen display of the diagram. I want to be able to take a shot of rectangle areas in the full-screen mode. 
I don't want to use print screen to file then open the file then edit it.
I use Snipp tool but when in full-screen mode, the tool does not recognize the hot keys.
Any suggestions (free tools only please)!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) and cannot recommend it enough. Any questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but Greenshot takes a fullscreen capture, could it be configured for partial screen area in full-screen mode?

Comment: Absolutely; `Right click > Preferences...` You can set hot keys for capturing full screen, window, region or last region. By default I configure region as the `Prnt scrn` key and capture full screen it set to `Ctrl` + `Prnt scrn`

Answer (score 1):

there may be free tools compatible with Visio, but for me, best tool is IRFANView icon pinned to taskbar.

Alt+ PrtScan for window capture
click Iview icon
^V (paste)
draw rectangle 
^Y (crop)
^s (save)
choose file name and path... done
with practise, and repetition, takes me 10 sec.
IRFANView 32/64 is full featured menu optioned (not fat GUI App) image editor, resizer, compressor, save as any format, read any format and can use Adobe filters, Edit > show toolbar to add text, arrows eraser, clone zones etc.

Lean and fast but for those who prefer hotkeys. 100x better than MSpaint and faster than PSP, alternatives are GIMP.

But for single purpose screen save, use other suggested Apps IF you can use timed screen shot, flip screen ALT+Tab and capture array??

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation of this tool, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

GreenShot, Lightshot there are alot of tools

However the community is actually not allowed to recommend software sinds this is an Q&A site and is against the terms.